# Many histograms with VBA macro

Tags: vba, excel

I recorded a macro that creates a histogram. The code is this

```
Sub histcreate

  Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Histogram", ActiveSheet.Range( _
    "$A$3:$A$1601"), ActiveSheet.Range("$BH$1"), , False, False, True, _
    True
End Sub
```

I want to modify this macro, so that it creates not only this one histogram, but 50 histograms with ranges

```
"$B$3:$B$1601"  
"$C$3:$C$1601"
```

and so on. I think I should use a for loop, but I don't know how to loop through letters. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (untested, but revised per comments).  This uses the `.Offset` method with a counter/loop variable, `i`, inside a loop.

```
Sub histcreate
Dim firstRange as Range
Dim secondRange as Range
Dim numberOfColumns as Long

'### How many columns wide is the data which will plot as histograms?
numberOfColumns = 50

'### Define the first column of data used for the histogram
Set firstRange = ActiveSheet.Range("$A$3:$A$1601")

'### Define the second range (originally $BH$1)
Set secondRange = ActiveSheet.Range("$BH$1)

For i = 0 to (numColumns -1)
    Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Histogram", _
        firstRange.Offset(0,i).Address, _
        secondRange.Offset(0,i*2), _
        , False, False, True, True
Next

End Sub
```

**Update from comments**

I think there is something wrong with your function call.  Examples I find elsewhere show different arguments or at the least, they do not *omit* a range argument.  See for example **[HERE](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/7ed39841-3502-4f69-9ded-ac41b102b99e/histogram-from-excel-vba?forum=exceldev)**.

Examples given [HERE](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/718071-drawing-a-histogram-using-a-macro.html) suggest a different order of the arguments, with the first and third arguments as Range objects, and second argument given as a `""` null string.

This function is not well-documented, but I think if you follow the first link and try and figure out what the three range arguments need to be, then you will be able to update this code as needed.

Comment: Thanks! `$BH$1` is the first cell of the 2 column output. So I need to 
shift that by 2. so `$BH$1` `$BJ$1` `$BL$1`

Comment: see revision to the answer, above.

Comment: Thanks, but I get the " input range must be contiguous" error.

Comment: See revisions. The Histogram function is not well-documented, but appears you are missing an argument maybe.